# How do I organize imports automatically in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I find myself typing `Ctrl+Shift+O` several times to organize imports (usually imports which are no longer required, generating warnings).

Is there to make Eclipse do this every once in a while or, at least, every time I save a file?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions->Configure...

You can configure the removal of unused imports when saving from the Unnecessary Code tab.

Adding imports would normally be done as you are writing the code otherwise it won't compile.

This is how it looks like: [image]

Comment: I never knew about Save Actions before. Useful stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Doing while saving is great, but if you already have lots of files that need it applied to you can also select the package in the `Package Explorer` and go to `Source->Organise Imports` It will apply to each file below that package.

You may be doing this already, I just wanted to make it clear that it can be applied to many files as can `Source->Format`.

Answer (score 3):

Either:
<project>->Properties->Java Editor->Save Actions

Or

Windows->Preferences->Java->Editor->Save Actions

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is called `Save Actions`. There you can enable several thing should be done when saving a file.