# Default imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to customize the default imports in Eclipse?

For example if I open a new JUnit Test Class by default I get these imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
```

What I'd like to get:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Comment: please go through this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6293513/1944782

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, Eclipse is quite lacking in the customizability of code generation when refactoring and creating new entities.

You might want to check out [Eclipse Optimize Imports to Include Static Imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288861/eclipse-optimize-imports-to-include-static-imports) for information how to make content assist find static methods in predefined classes. That might be what you actually want. In the accepted answer Joey Gibson writes that you can add `org.hamcrest.Matchers` to  **Window » Preferences » Java » Editor » Content Assist » Favorites**.

---

Another solution to the specific problem of statically importing Hamcrest methods, is to configure a *Code Template* named hamcrest instead. That way you can simply type *ham* and follow up with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to get the import at the top.

The template should look like

```
${staticImport:importStatic('org.hamcrest.Matchers.*')}${cursor}
```

An even more convenient hack is to add this template to the already existing `test` code template which generates a new test method. If you change this template to:

```
@${testType:newType(org.junit.Test)}
public void ${testName}() throws Exception {
    ${staticImport1:importStatic('org.hamcrest.Matchers.*')}
    ${staticImport2:importStatic('org.junit.Assert.*')}${cursor}
}
```

and use this each time you make a new test method you will never have to care about adding the hamcrest import manually again.

Image to show where you configure it:
[image: hamcrest code template]

Comment: Favorites are a way to go

Answer (score 7):

The closest preference I can find is the one under **Window --> Preferences --> Java --> Code Templates**. Expand the **Code** section and select the **New Java files** option to view the pattern for newly created Java files. You can then click **Edit** to add the import, for instance:

```
${filecomment}
${package_declaration}

import org.hamcrest.*;

${typecomment}
${type_declaration}
```

In all cases you still need to write the code that uses the `org.hamcrest` package. Alternatively, just organize the imports by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> after adding the code that uses the package.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you to add `org.hamcrest.Matchers.*` into “Favorites” (**Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Favorites**).

This way content assist will propose static members even if the import is missing and add corresponding import when you use the member.
It means you can type the method/field you’d like to use and let content assist add the import automatically.

Answer (score 0):

### Organize Imports

Modern IDEs offer a feature called [Organize Imports](http://java.dzone.com/articles/organize-imports-eclipse). Using this feature you can no longer be worried about those import statements, the IDE itself manage those imports.

### How should you do

As you write your codes, whenever you want to make the IDE to organize your imports, you should just press its shortcut keys.

Keyboard: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Menu: **`Source`** → **`Organize Imports`**

### How it works

IDE search through your codes and lookup each class and add their corresponding import statements. Also unused imported classes will be removed.

Comment: For static imports as the OP provides in the example, this does not really help. Eclipse does not add static imports on _Organize Imports_.

Answer (score -6):

In Netbeans you can navigate through this , **Tools-->templates-->java Folder-->** you can give what you need to want while opening a page Example :there will be Java class,interface,enum,exception etc