# Making a package default like java.lang in java

Tags: java

what I mean by making a package default is including the java package into the class mainstream just like `java.lang`

suppose I Have a package `utility.*` I want this package to be imported by default in any class I create.

Hence, whenever I'd create a class, I wouldn't have to write the import statement at all, as we don't have to in the case of `java.lang`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can't do that. Only `java.lang` is "auto-imported" and that's done by the spec, there's no way to add other auto-imports.

Comment: If you use an IDE you might be able to create some kind of template, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582625/default-imports-in-eclipse).

Answer (score 2):

Only `java.lang` is auto-imported this way and there's no way to add other packages to this list (outside of building your own version of Java, which is **definitely** a bad idea).

However, most IDEs allow you to define "favorite" packages that will be searched first for suggestions when writing a class name that hasn't been imported there and adding your package to that list has a *very* similar effect, since the IDE will just add the import statement for you.

Comment: Thanks. Does BlueJ do so?

Comment: @Vulcan: I don't know.