# eclipse not adding packages automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am trying to display a message on a label using eclipse and java. The first issue that I am having when I create the `JFrame`. It is that eclipse is not automatically adding the import packages. ie. `import javax.swing.JLabel`. The second problem is that once I type the import package, I still get error messages like, "The import `javax.swing.Jlabel` cannot be resolved." So in the code below, some of imports I had to manually put in and some where put in automatically when I dragged the object from the palette and dropped it in the design view.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Jlabel;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class frame1 {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame1 window = new frame1();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public frame1() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 889, 622);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("showMessage");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                //lbldisplayMessage.setText
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setForeground(new Color(153, 51, 51));
        btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Script MT Bold", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(360, 449, 145, 40);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("The Message Goes here");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(28, 124, 160, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JLabel lbldisplayMessage = new JLabel("");
        lbldisplayMessage.setBounds(162, 124, 200, 50);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lbldisplayMessage);
    }
}
```

Comment: `javax.swing.Jlabel;` must be `javax.swing.JLabel;`. Don't write imports by hand, use hot keys to organize imports (ctrl+shift+o for windows by default). Also read [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293475/organize-imports-automatically)

Comment: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Eclipse.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for your information,
***eclipse do not add packages automatically***

-- You have to manually import it or by using Hot keys

for imports you can use

> ctrl+shift+o

Comment: when you use help of "ctrl+space" after typing few initial characters then it will import packages automaticaly

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you add the JRE library to classpath :

```
Project > Build Path > Configure build path... > Libraries tab > Add library > JRE System Library
```

Comment: the problem is with the case of L in `JLabel` and not of the library.

Comment: he has it in his question *"The import javax.swing.Jlabel cannot be resolved."*

Comment: There were two issues present in the question. The first issue was pointing out that eclipse does not automatically imports the packages. I thought that's the issue that flafoux was trying to address in his response. The second issue was answered by Alex2410 comment. The lower case l was Changed captial L and it solved the error message. But the packages are still not automatically added when dragging labels  or text boxes as I see  in some tutorials.