# Custom settings for Eclipse IDE - Can I do stuff like this?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, ide, preferences

I looked through the settings/plugin pages but couldn't find what I needed, I am hoping to make the following things possible:

1. While typing, eclipse should give me live predictions of what I could type next - Android Studio uses this feature, it shows me immediately what I maybe want to use, even whole Overrides can be live predicted - Eclipse otherwise doesn't show me anything right now...
2. When saving automatically import missing classes
3. When creating a new class automatically load a customizable preset instead of the empty class
4. A theme like the popular dark theme "Moonrise UI" but with lighter gray background color.. Couldn't find one :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959946/ctrl-space-in-eclipse-without-pressing-ctrl-space) or

`window > preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Auto activation triggers for java > (type) ._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

**2.** [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293475/organize-imports-automatically) or

`window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > (Configure)`

**3.** code templates `(window > preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Teplates > Code > New Java Files (and/or Class body)`

**4.** ...

Comment: When I get the predictions, I'm used to press tab to paste it, but somehow it just jumps into that dialog, how is that shortcut called so I can change it to tab?

Comment: Enter key is doing what you want. tab is needed to jump that dialog.